# Faster alternatives to append inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, append

I have two dataframes, one about some households (`df_men`), and one about individuals of these households (`df_ind`). Every household has a unique ID (`id`), and every individual has the ID of his household. For each household, I want to know the age of the household head. A person is the head when `LIEN_CM==0`. I used the following code:

```
age_hh <- c()

for (i in df_ind$id) {
  b <- df_ind[df_ind$id==i & df_ind$LIEN_CM==0,]$AGE1
  age_hh <- append(age_hh, b)
}
```

where `age_hh` is a vector of ages. However, since my individuals' data frame is quite long (3,341,426 rows), the loop is taking so long to give results. Therefore, I would like to know if there is a faster method to compute the ages' vector. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I attempted the method suggested in the first comment, but it gives strange results; my data frame has only 730,099 households:

```
> dim(df_men)
[1] 730099     43
```

and therefore there are only 730,099 heads:

```
> table(df_ind$LIEN_CM)

      0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9 
 730099  561080 1558839  163435   60048   75679   89529   69358    4360   22845
```

But when I try the first comment, it gives me a vector of 736,253 ages,

```
> df_ind[df_ind$LIEN_CM==0,'AGE1']
# A tibble: 736,253 × 1
   AGE1       
   <dbl+lbl>  
 1 NA         
 2 17 [17 ans]
 3 NA         
 4 NA         
 5 NA         
 6 NA         
 7 NA         
 8 NA         
 9 NA         
10 NA         
# ℹ 736,243 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

most of which are `NA`s.

```
> sum(is.na(df_ind[df_ind$LIEN_CM==0,'AGE1']))
[1] 724462
```

As to the second comment, it takes very long (it is still running).

**Update 2**

```
> sum(df_ind$LIEN_CM==0)
[1] NA
> sum(df_ind$LIEN_CM==0, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 730099
```

This is the output of the `dput()` function:

```
> dput(head(df_ind[c("id","LIEN_CM","AGE1")], n = 100))
structure(list(id = c(25500L, 25500L, 25501L, 25501L, 25501L, 
25501L, 25501L, 25502L, 25502L, 25502L, 25502L, 25502L, 25503L, 
25503L, 25503L, 25503L, 25503L, 25503L, 25503L, 25504L, 25504L, 
25504L, 25504L, 25504L, 25505L, 25506L, 25506L, 25507L, 25508L, 
25508L, 25508L, 25508L, 25509L, 25510L, 25510L, 25510L, 25510L, 
25510L, 25511L, 25511L, 25511L, 25511L, 25511L, 25511L, 25511L, 
25511L, 25511L, 25512L, 25512L, 25512L, 25512L, 25512L, 25513L, 
25514L, 25514L, 25514L, 25514L, 25514L, 25515L, 25515L, 25515L, 
25516L, 25516L, 25516L, 25516L, 25516L, 25516L, 25516L, 25517L, 
25517L, 25517L, 25517L, 25518L, 25518L, 25518L, 25518L, 25518L, 
25518L, 25519L, 25519L, 25519L, 25519L, 25519L, 25519L, 25519L, 
25520L, 25520L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 
25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L, 25521L), LIEN_CM = c(0, 
4, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 5, 5, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3), AGE1 = c(NA, NA, 
17, 20, 22, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, 18, 
NA, NA, NA, 8, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 10, 5, 1, NA, NA, 20, 17, 13, 9, 21, 22, 0, NA, NA, NA, 24, 
2, 20, NA, NA, 5, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, 13, 6, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA, 21, 19, 17, 9, NA, NA, 24, 21, 19, 18, 
17, NA, 23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18, 15, NA, NA, 14, 10, 5
)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: No need of for-loop just do `df_ind[df_ind$LIEN_CM==0,'AGE1']`

Comment: `library(dplyr); df_ind %>% left_join(df_ind %>% filter(LIEN_CM == 0) %>% select(id, age_hh = AGE1))`. This will append `age_hh` where that is the age associated with the head of household for the respective `id`, and should be orders of magnitude faster than your loop.

Comment: or even `subset(df_ind, LIEN == 0)`

Comment: @JonSpring Your answer is taking a lot of time, it's still running.

Comment: what is the results when you run `sum(df_ind$LIEN == 0)`?

Comment: Odd. I mocked up some sample data with 4M rows and 1.7M id's, and the code ran in about a second for me. Perhaps you could create some sample data that has properties like your data?

Comment: Here's my sample data. `library(dplyr); set.seed(123); id_n <- 2E6; n <- 4E6; df_ind <- data.frame(id   = sample(1:id_n, size = n, replace = TRUE), LIEN_CM = sample(1:20, size = n, replace = TRUE),  AGE1 = sample(0:99, size = n, replace = TRUE)) %>% arrange(id) %>% mutate(LIEN_CM = if_else(id != lag(id, default = 0), 0, LIEN_CM)) %>% slice_sample(n = n)`.  It's 4M rows long with 1.7M distinct id's, where only one row per id has LIEN_CM == 0.

Comment: Please try to make your question reproducible, by either sharing a subset of data with `dput()` or by generating some fake data with the characteristics you care about. It sounds like your `df_ind$LIEN_CM` column has 6,154 NA's in it, which is why you see 730,099 0's in `table(df_ind$LIEN_CM)` but the output from the first comment (which include LIEN_CM==0 but also is.na(LIEN_CM)) produces 736k rows. It looks like a great deal of your AGE1 values are NA as well. I wonder if you also have many NAs in `id`, as that would slow down a join if we don't filter them out first.

Comment: I expect using `filter(LIEN_CM == 0 & !is.na(id)) %>%` in my suggestion above should run faster if you have rows with NA for id. `sum(is.na(df_ind$id))` would count those.

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for your comments, I added the output of the `dput()` command. `sum(is.na(df_ind$id))` gives 0.

Comment: @onyambu I added the result of `sum(df_ind$LIEN_CM==0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in the first comment, and it worked.

```
df_ind %>% left_join(df_ind %>% drop_na(LIEN_CM) %>% filter(LIEN_CM==0) %>% select(id,age_hh=AGE1))
```